# multiple max() in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day all,

I have :-

```
 SELECT MAX(register_number) AS "Next-6-months-register-number" 
    FROM gypsum WHERE test_frequency ='6'
```

I should like to return the values for `test_frequency ='3'` and `'12'` in the same query.Is this possible?
Thanks GWS.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. Use `GROUP BY` to get the maximum value for each group:

```
SELECT test_frequency, MAX(register_number) AS "Max-register-number"
FROM gypsum
WHERE test_frequency IN ('3', '6', '12')
GROUP BY test_frequency
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN test_frequency = '3' THEN register_number END) 
      AS "Next-3-months-register-number",
  MAX(CASE WHEN test_frequency = '12' THEN register_number END) 
      AS "Next-12-months-register-number",
  MAX(CASE WHEN test_frequency = '6' THEN register_number END) 
      AS "Next-6-months-register-number",
  MAX(register_number) AS "Next-6-months-register-number" 
FROM gypsum
```

Comment: Thank you Mamoud this works but returns 4 columns with the 12 repeated

Comment: @user1731603 remove `test_frequency` and `GROUP BY test_frequency` as well. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(CASE 
                WHEN test_frequency ='6' THEN register_number 
           ELSE NULL END) AS "Next-6-months-register-number" ,
      MAX(CASE 
                WHEN test_frequency ='3' THEN register_number 
           ELSE NULL END) AS "Next-3-months-register-number" ,
     MAX(CASE 
                WHEN test_frequency ='12' THEN register_number 
           ELSE NULL END) AS "Next-12-months-register-number" 
FROM gypsum
```

Comment: Thank you rs I could not get this to work there is an error:rror Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS "Next-6-months-register-number" ,
      MAX(CASE 
                WHEN te' at line 3

Comment: Thanks rs but I still get the error : Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(CASE 
                WHEN test_frequency ='3' THEN register_number 
     ' at line 4

Comment: check now, query was missing one comma between columns

Answer (score 0):

To get Max value for all test_frequency

```
SELECT test_frequency ,MAX(register_number) AS "Next-6-months-register-number" 
FROM gypsum 
group by test_frequency
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(register_number) AS "Next-6-months-register-number" 
FROM gypsum WHERE test_frequency in('6','3','12')
group by test_frequency
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the extra parameters with the **OR** keyword.

```
SELECT MAX(register_number) AS "Next-6-months-register-number" FROM gypsum 
WHERE test_frequency ='6'
or 
test_frequency ='3'
or
test_frequency ='12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here , you add your test frequency..('3','12).. or select from query like :

```
SELECT test_frequency, MAX(register_number) AS "Max-register-number"
FROM gypsum
WHERE test_frequency IN ('3','12')
GROUP BY test_frequency
```

---

```
SELECT test_frequency, MAX(register_number) AS "Max-register-number"
FROM gypsum
WHERE test_frequency IN (select frequency_colname from tablename where colname=value)
GROUP BY test_frequency
```